# How to create NSDatePicker with pop graphic calendar?

Tags: macos, nsdateformatter, nsdatepicker

Im trying to create a text field with a calendar pop just like you see in the Calendar App of MacOS:

[Calendar pop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtLJi.png)

I imagined it would be something native, but can't quite find how to implement it for MacOS. If you could give me tips of which elements are being used I appreciate.

Comment: Hope this blog might help you:http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nsdatepicker-sample-code/ and source can be [downloaded here](http://www.knowstack.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/NSDatePickerSampleCode.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented such a functionality in one of my Apps. There is nothing native available in macOS. To get this behavior you can use a border less window with a custom shape. The window can be opened relative to the view triggering the action. In the window you can use a regular NSDatePicker.

[image]

Let me know if you need further help.

[Sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/MarcTeichmann/macOS-Calendar-DatePicker)

All the best.

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. I have a question for you: Is it possible to make a window relative to a view or another window? How did you manage to do that?

I was able to do it by creating a view on top of another view. Which for me, it is not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: To use a view is not a good idea. The window approach is how its done by Apple as well. Unfortunately is my code  still in objective-c but I will migrate it to Swift and make the code available for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it took some longer to migrate the code to swift but finally its there. I updated my answer with the link